# Access a control of a datatemplate (listview) from code

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a listview with a custom datatemplate, that each ListViewItem has a text, an author and a date. Something like this

```
texttexttexttext
Author     Date
```

Now I want to create multiple Items and adjust on every item these three textboxes.

Comment: The question is rather unclear. Do you want a different datatemplate (layout) for every item or do you want the 3 textboxes be filled with different text/data for ever item you add?

Comment: I'm going to guess that there is a better way of positioning them than using code-behind.  Give us more detail and we can figure something out.

Comment: I want that each time the text is different. Hope that it's now clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use data bindings:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</List>
```

List is defined in view model and an `ObservableCollection<Item>`.

Item:

```
public class Item : INofifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string author; 
    public string Author
    {
        get { return author; }
        set 
        {
            author = value;
            var copy = PropertyChanged; // avoid concurrent changes
            if (copy != null)
                copy(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Search the internet for more complete binding tutorials...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can do this with the `FindName` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx)) but it seems this method is missing in the Windows 8 WinRT framework and I haven't found another way to accomplish this...

Comment: mhm...is there a other way to change the text on every ListViewItem?